# Please contact our office and we will arrange for a sales representative to call on you. (call on = visit)

Tags: idioms, phrasal-verbs

> Please contact our office and we will arrange for a sales representative to **call on** you. He will be glad to explain our terms, discount policies, and sales procedures.

call on sb : visit

Wonder why 'call on' equals 'visit'.

Comment: Because it just does! One meaning of _call_ (noun) is a short visit to someone else's house, usually social but also for business purposes, from which we get the phrasal verbs _pay a call to_ and _call on_.

Comment: The full OED has section V - ***Senses in which visiting or paying a call is the primary meaning*** - with definition 32a (intransitive) *To make a visit to a house or premises; to pay a call. Frequently with **at** specifying the house or premises visited; also with **by, round.*** Interestingly, the full OED says this usage is ***rare** in North American use*. But there's no mention of that in their more *specific* definition 3 (intransitive) *To make a short visit to (a person); **to pay a call on**.*